# include udf in python?

Tags: python, import, cross-platform

i've a small user defined function in python, say fib(n), how do i use that in other programs or modules?
`def fib(n):`

should i use import or is there any other feature?

Also i'm learning python in eclipse IDE, it wont support

`print "any string"`

but i'm forced to use like, 
`print("string")`

in python manual online, its given its cross platform and same syntax, but why like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use import to include the function in other programs. Just say `import mymodule` where the code is located in file `mymodule.py`. Then say `mymodule.fib` to use the function.

To answer your second question: The syntax `print "any string"` is acceptable in Python 2, but is no longer allowed in Python 3.

Comment: previously i was trying to importing function itself!! now i get them working, thanks......